# Find uptime of 'apache2'

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

How can I find the uptime of Apache2. There are numerous suggestions out there to use

```
httpd fullstatus
```

But this fails

```
-bash: httpd: command not found
```

There is no httpd command running in `top` either, just an apache2 process.

I also tried (without any luck)

```
httpd status
apache2 status
apache2 fullstatus
/usr/sbin/apache2 fullstatus
/usr/sbin/apache2 status
```

What command can I use to find apache2's uptime reliably given the differences in how Apache is installed/configured on various platforms?

Comment: To what precision do you need the answer?  Will +/- 1 day do?

Comment: Yes MadHatter. Basically I want to know was it started just now (5 seconds) or some time ago. Its to check that the restart command actually ran.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `ps -eo comm,etime` for example:

```
$ ps -eo comm,etime | grep httpd
httpd            5-01:40:22
```

This shows the elapsed time since the process was started. Mine is showing 5 days, 1 hr, 40 mins, 22 secs.

And after a restart:

```
$ ps -eo comm,etime | grep httpd
httpd                 00:07
```

In a graceful restart, if an apache process is still serving a connection it won't be killed until it finishes, so if it's a large download to a slow host, it may linger for a while until it completes.

I did snip most of the output as it shows each forked process, but you will have a general overview of how long it has been running.

Comment: Another version of this worked for me `ps --no-headers -o etime -C apache2`

Comment: That was originally what I was going to post (`ps -o etime -C httpd`), but when I tested it, I typo'ed so it didn't work correctly, so I showed the grep version instead thinking something wasn't working as I thought it would. Glad you got it to work!

Comment: I used @MadHatter's `netstat` trick (below) to figure out that I should be grepping for `nginx` using this command. Got my uptime! :-)

Answer (score 7):

I suspect there are lots of apache-version-specific ways to do this, but one generally-valid (and slightly brute-force) way is as follows.

Find the PID of the process that has the port open; it will have been the first one started:

```
[root@lory ~]# netstat -apn|grep -w 80|grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      2903/httpd
```

The `netstat` command requires privilege, so run as root or under `sudo`.  In this case the PID is 2903.  Then find how long that process has been running:

```
[root@lory ~]# ps auxww|grep 2903|grep -v grep
apache    2903  0.0  1.0 413316 39972 ?        S    Oct23   0:42 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

In this case, the start time is Oct 23, so I've been running a couple of days.  You might get a field like 11:15, in which case it's a time of day, today, so you know the restart's worked.

Comment: Great. One sureshot result in one line.

Answer (score 6):

If you have [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) installed you should be able to determine the uptime with:

```
apachectl status
```

Which will show the current time as well as the last restart time. It might be version/dstro specific, but my debian servers show "Server uptime" in the output as well

Comment: I do not have it installed, but good call +1

Comment: You also don't have to use `apachectl` -- `http://127.0.0.1/status` (or wherever mod_status is configured - localhost is the default) will get you the same thing if the module is installed & configured to accept requests from your location. We allow our monitoring system to get the status page on our internal servers for convenience.